# How long does it take (on average/etimated) a neuron to fire?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, brain

I'm not from a neuroscience field but I'm curious about this. I would like to know how long does it take for the membrane potential of a neuron to go from its resting value to its threshold value ( where the neuron is said to fire an action potential) ? I know that are all plenty of type of neurons, and that after firing that neuron goes through a "refractory period". According to the website in the link below, the absolute refractory period last around 1-2ms and the relative one 3-4ms. But I wasn't able to find any discussion on the lasting period that it takes the neuron to fire. I wanted to know how faster it is in comparison with the refractory period. Of course, I just would like to know some rough estimation. It would be really nice if someone could point it out some reference/paper/book where this time difference is discussed, since I have to cite this for a homework I'm doing for school.  Thank you very much in advance!

website:https://aiimpacts.org/rate-of-neuron-firing/#easy-footnote-bottom-8-142

Comment: Totally depends on the input.